# How to select fields from other table based on different criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a [Products] table with

```
ProductID | Productname 

1         | Bike
2         | Car
```

and a table [Stores] with quantity in 2 different wharehouses, the first wharehouse is the 1 and the second is the 2.

The table [Stores] have the ID of the products

```
ID |ProductID | Qty |wharehouse

1  |1         | 10  |1
2  |1         | 5   |2
3  |2         | 6   |1
4  |2         | 7   |2
```

I want to make a query to show in one record for each product, the following

ProductID, ProductName, QtyFromFirstWhareHouse, QtyFromSecondWhareHouse

I tried to make a second query for each qty but i dont what criteria to give into.
Thank you

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Based in the square braces, I am guessing your database is really MS Access.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually is MySQL, but i've imported to Access because of the query tools Access provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correlated subqueries might be the simplest solution:

```
select p.*,
       (select s.qty
        from stores as s
        where s.productid = p.productid and s.warehouse = 1
       ) as quantity_1,
       (select s.qty
        from stores as s
        where s.productid = p.productid and s.warehouse = 2
       ) as quantity_2
from products as p;
```

Note:  This assumes that there is one row in the `stores` table for each warehouse/product combination.  If there are multiple rows, then you want aggregation of some sort, such as `sum(s.qty)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but i get error that this query will return only one record and stopped. because some values are duplicate on the table Stores. thanks again